# Building site via devenv.exe works, msbuild fails

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, devenv

I'm on VS2012 Update 3 using TFS2012.

I build the same solution using devenv and msbuild.  When I get to the Web Site projects, devenv doesn't report any errors, but msbuild does repeatedly.  Sample of the logs for both:

**Devenv:**

```
114>------ Build started: Project: C:\...\API\, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------  
114>Could not get dependencies for project reference 'A'Could not get dependencies for     project reference 'BusinessLogic' Could not get dependencies for project reference 'BusinessLogic.ASPAgents' Could not get dependencies for project reference 'DataAccessLogicComponents' Could not get dependencies for project reference 'UI'Validating Web Site
114>Building directory '/API/'.  
114>  
114>Validation Complete
```

**MSBuild:**

```
121>C:\Scrubbed\API.metaproj : warning MSB3274: The primary reference "C:\Scrubbed\PreMVC\A\bin\Release\A.dll" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".  
121>C:\Scrubbed\API.metaproj : warning MSB3274: The primary reference "C:\Scrubbed\PreMVC\BusinessLogic\bin\Release\A.Web.BusinessLogic.dll" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".  
121>C:\Scrubbed\API.metaproj : warning MSB3275: The primary reference "C:\Scrubbed\PreMVC\BusinessLogic\bin\Release\A.Web.BusinessLogic.dll" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the assembly "A, Version=0.0.0.15, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=060d385c0c45e767" which was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".  

     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v /API -p PreMVC\API\ -u -f PrecompiledWeb\API\ 

121>C:\Scrubbed\PreMVC\API\App_Code\File1.cs(7): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'BusinessLogic' does not exist in the namespace 'A.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Scrubbed\API.metaproj]  
121>C:\Scrubbed\PreMVC\API\App_Code\File1.cs(8): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist in the namespace 'A.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Scrubbed\API.metaproj]  
121>C:\Scrubbed\PreMVC\API\App_Code\File1.cs(12): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist in the namespace 'A.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Scrubbed\API.metaproj]  
121>C:\Scrubbed\PreMVC\API\App_Code\File2.cs(7): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'BusinessLogic' does not exist in the namespace 'A.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Scrubbed\API.metaproj]
121>C:\Scrubbed\PreMVC\API\App_Code\File2.cs(8): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist in the namespace 'A.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Scrubbed\API.metaproj]  
121>C:\Scrubbed\PreMVC\API\App_Code\File2.cs(12): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist in the namespace 'A.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Scrubbed\API.metaproj]
121>C:\Scrubbed\PreMVC\API\App_Code\File3.cs(7): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'BusinessLogic' does not exist in the namespace 'A.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Scrubbed\API.metaproj]
121>C:\Scrubbed\PreMVC\API\App_Code\File3.cs(8): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist in the namespace 'A.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Scrubbed\API.metaproj]  
121>Done Building Project "C:\Scrubbed\API.metaproj" (Rebuild target(s)) -- FAILED.
```

Any idea as to why Devenv carries on but MSBuild fails immediately?

Comment: Running devenv from the command prompt might differ from using msbuild in that it might pull in some user/ui settings that aren't in play for msbuild. Just a random thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an answer from a mod on MSDN forums.  Basically MSBuild is extremely strict about dependencies where devenv just puts up warnings but carries on.

We ended up getting the go-ahead to move to .NET 4.5 entirely so we fixed the mismatch and ended up moving our build to MSBuild.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add project references to the other projects and that they are all using the same version of .NET framework.

Comment: I'm asking why one seems to work and one seems to fail.  I updated the projects to .NET 4.5 anyhow and switched to MSBuild since devenv randomly (on occasion - like 1 out of 15 builds) has "A task was canceled" issues.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the warning in your logs tell the story?

"121>C:\Scrubbed\API.metaproj : warning MSB3274: The primary reference "C:\Scrubbed\PreMVC\A\bin\Release\A.dll" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".  "

Comment: The question (I think) is why does it work for one but not the other.